# Rails engine not caching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, rails-engines

In development I am trying to gather all models within my app by including a method within `ActiveRecord::Base` classes so they can configure the models and it will give me a hook to add that model to a global array.

```
module EngineName
  module ActiveRecordExtensions
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do
      def self.inherited(klass) #:nodoc:
        klass.class_eval do
          def self.config_block(&block)
            abstract_model = EngineName::AbstractModel.new(self)
            abstract_model.instance_eval(&block) if block

            EngineName::Models.add(abstract_model)
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

My `EngineName::Models` class is just a wrapper that holds all models.

```
module EngineName
  class Models
    class << self
      def all
        @models ||= []
      end
      alias_method :models, :all

      def navigation
        @models - excluded_navigation_models
      end

      def routed
        @models - excluded_route_models
      end

      # Creates an array of models if none exists. Appends new models
      # if the instance variable already exists.
      def register(klass)
        if @models.nil?
          @models = [klass]
        else
          @models << klass unless @models.include?(klass) || excluded_models.include?(klass)
        end
      end
      alias_method :add, :register
    end
  end
end
```

On each refresh though, the `config_block` method within my model gets called and in turn appends the same model over and over within my global array of models.

As you can see down below, whenever I loop through all my models, it will keep on appending itself.

[image]

Is there any way to cache certain classes within my engine? Or is there a flaw within my approach of registering models with a hook within the model itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that in your development environment your models get reloaded on every request so that changes to these classes take effect and you don't have to re-boot your server every time you make a change to your source code. You can see this behavior in the console:

```
User.object_id
=> 2203143360
reload!
=> true
User.object_id
=> 2212653160
```

What this means is that when you call `@models.include?(klass)` you are actually checking your current instantiation of that object against one from a previous request. What you'll notice is that over time your memory gets bloated because these objects will not be deleted - since garbage collection will keep them around because of the reference to them in your @models instance variable. This won't be a problem in production, because classes are only loaded once, but it will cause you problems in development.

To get around this I would recommend doing something like this:

```
module EngineName
  class Models
    class << self
      def all
        @models ||= {}
      end
      alias_method :models, :all

      def register(klass)
        if @models.nil?
          @models = {klass.name => klass}
        else
          @models[klass.name] = klass unless excluded_models.keys.include?(klass.name)
        end
      end
      alias_method :add, :register
    end
  end
end
```

Using a hash will let you keep track of models by their names, and whenever a new version of a model comes around it will replace the old out-dated version. This should help in your development environment. To get a list of all the models you'll simply use `@models.values` and to get a list of the model names you'll simply use `@models.keys`.

Comment: I will try this out and let you know how it goes, thank you! I would mark it as correct, but i'd like to try it out first… if you don't mind :)

Comment: This works and feels more logical... allows me to break it up as well incase I want some models only in certain places. Thanks again!